# Unable to grab a text from html soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML as follows:

```
<span class="tips yjSt" id="takane">その日はじめ（寄り付き）から現在までで、最も高かった値段</span></dt>
</dl>
</div>
<div class="lineFi clearfix">
<dl class="tseDtl"><dd class="ymuiEditLink mar0">
<strong>189.1</strong><span class="date yjSt">（09:00）</span><span class="icoRealTime" title="リアルタイム"> </span></dd>
<dt class="title">安値<a class="tips alignPos" data-ylk="slk:word;pos:4"
```

I tried to extract 189.1

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
res = soup.find_all("dl", {"class": "ymuiEditLink mar0"})
print (res)
```

but result is empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag mentioned in findall should be `dd`

**Ex:**

```
html = """<span class="tips yjSt" id="takane">その日はじめ（寄り付き）から現在までで、最も高かった値段</span></dt>
</dl>
</div>
<div class="lineFi clearfix">
<dl class="tseDtl"><dd class="ymuiEditLink mar0">
<strong>189.1</strong><span class="date yjSt">（09:00）</span><span class="icoRealTime" title="リアルタイム"> </span></dd>
<dt class="title">安値<a class="tips alignPos" data-ylk="slk:word;pos:4" """
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
res = soup.find_all("dd", {"class": "ymuiEditLink mar0"})
print(res[0].strong.text)
```

**Output:**

```
189.1
```